# Projection string for GOES-WEST

Tags: coordinate-system, satellite

Full-res, full-disk GOES-WEST images are available from
goes.gsfc.nasa.gov.  Is it possible to rig up a projection
string for these images?

We know the center pixel is at (0N, 135W) and the
satellite elevation is 35,786km.  ARC has a "View from Space"
variant of the orthographic projection.  Can this be modified
to provide Lat/Lon coordinates for pixels on the image?

It doesn't have to be perfect, but I'd like to overlay coastal
boundaries.

PS: Don't know offhand if 35Kkm is from sea-level or from the earth's center.

Comment: Tim, you may feel free to provide contact information in your user profile, but please do not include it in questions.